# Pegar ID do Foreach na mesma página com session

Tags: php

Seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um jeito de atualizar a data da notificação no banco, só que para atualizar essa data eu preciso do ID do registro. Consigo trazer do banco esse ID sem problema, o problema é quando o cara clica na div, não sei como identificar o id em qual ele clicou. Tentei usar $_Session (fiz uma vez assim só que ele envia para outra página, daí rolou), porém ele está sobrepondo os valores na variável. (O id é o do registro, não da Div).

Códigos:

```
    foreach ($notificacoes as $notificacao): 
    ?>    

    <center>
    <?php
        echo $notificacao['datareg'];
        if(!empty($notificacao['datareg'])){
            echo '<div id="'. $div . $cont . '" class="visualizado" onclick="visualizarNt()">';
        } else {
            echo '<div id="'. $div . $cont .'" class="naovisualizado" onclick="visualizarNt()">';
        }                                                                                            
    ?>       
            <table border = "1">

                <tr>
                    <td>Foto</td>
                    <td>Nome</td>
                    <td>Sobrenome</td>
                    <td>Detalhes</td>
                    <td>Data esperada</td>
                    <td>Perfil</td>
                    <td>Cancelar</td>
                    <?php
                    if ($notificacao['estadoContrato'] != 'ConfirmadoTecnico') {
                        echo '<td>Atualizar</td>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo $notificacao['foto'] ?>" width="40px" height="40px"</td>
                    <td><?php echo $notificacao['nome'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $notificacao['sobrenome'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $notificacao['detalhes'] ?></td>                    
                    <td><?php echo $notificacao['data_acertada'] ?></td>
                    <td><a href="pag_perfilAbertoTec.php">Visitar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="" onclick="cancelar(); return false;">Cancelar</a></td>
                    <?php
                    if ($notificacao['estadoContrato'] != 'ConfirmadoTecnico') {
                        echo '<td><a href="" onclick="atualizar(); return false;">Confirmar</a></td>';
                    }

                    $_SESSION['idContrato'] = $_SESSION['datareg'];
                    // Tentei assim, mas ele está sobrepondo..
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php $cont++; ?>
        </div></center>
    <?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você precisa; está bem confusa sua explicação. Tente ser mais direto e descritivo.

Comment: Ao fazer o Foreach consigo trazer os dados de cada registro, certo? no caso não estou conseguindo fazer uma forma de separar esses id's, pois se eu colocar na sessão os id's serão sobrepostos..

Comment: Qual o motivo de separar os ID's. É necessário que você explique o que deseja fazer para que possamos te ajudar; pelo o que entendi você recebe os ID's, mas não entendi quando se refere à "separar esses id... se eu colocar na sessão os id serão sobrepostos".

Comment: Eu preciso do ID para atualizar a data no BD quando o usuário clicar na div. Só que não sei como pegar esse id, primeiro como disse, se eu colocar na sessão ele vai ser sobreposto e segundo porque o código que atualiza está fora do foreach, aí não posso usar a variável $notificacao[]

Comment: Você tem duas opções. Utilizar javascript para recuperar o ID do elemento, ou através do link fazer uma requisição a uma página PHP que vai receber o método. Se for um conteúdo dinâmico, sugiro usar javascript.